# Magento2 get all product review details by product sku?

Tags: magento2, review, ratings

In Magento 2 how to get all the product reviews by product SKU.

Please find the screenshot below.

[image]
please provide/suggest me how to get.

I have written some test code:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo "All reviews of the product </br>";


$sku ='24-MB04';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$productObject = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStoreId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$product = $productObject->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is example to get product review by **product SKU or Product ID**

```
$sku = '24-MB02';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku); //use load($producID) if you have product id
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStoreId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$rating = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");

$collection = $rating->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $currentStoreId
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $product->getId()
        )->setDateOrder();

print_r($collection->getData()); //Get all review data of product
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: thanks for your reply @prince i am getting an array http://prntscr.com/g2ec3y but how to get these details http://prntscr.com/g2ebw8 please suggest me if i have used getData() method getting fatal error

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA plz check my updated answer you can get all review infor like title, description from `$collection`

Comment: thanks prince i have small doubt how can get rating percentage by review id? here

Comment: @PrincePatel  it is giving 0 review count and 0 review summary

Comment: @PrincePatel its worked actually untill and unless review not approved it is giving 0  value only

Answer (score 0):

Load **RatingSummary** by **$product** , Try below code :

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');

    $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);

    $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
```

Comment: thanks @manthan dave  for your reply but how to get remaining all the details as shown in the screenshot

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA check out $reviewFactory ->getData(); you will find all the details then get the details which you want by calling methods for the same

Comment: okay thanks let me check and get back to u dave..

Comment: @Manthan it is giving 0 review count and 0 review summary

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

set_time_limit(0);


use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include("app/bootstrap.php");

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');

$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$_categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');

$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

$scopeConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');

    $sku = 'WT09'; // YOU PRODUCT SKU

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $product = $objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

    $rating = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");
    $collection = $rating->create()
            ->addStatusFilter(
                \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
            )->addEntityFilter(
                'product',
                $product->getId()
            )->setDateOrder();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($collection->getData());
    echo "<pre>";
```